# Laravel - SQL query equals the value of id to null in many to many relationship

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, relationship

In model I have:

```
class Car extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'car_user', 'car_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

And in my controller I have:

```
\DB::enableQueryLog();
$cars = Car::with('users')->get();
dd(\DB::getQueryLog());
```

The queries executed are:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select * from `cars`"
    "bindings" => []
    "time" => 0.62
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select `users`.*, `car_user`.`user_id` as `pivot_user_id`, `car_user`.`car_id` as `pivot_car_id` from `users` inner join `car_user` on `users`.`user_id` = `car_user`.`car_id` where `car_user`.`user_id` in (?)"
    "bindings" => array:1 [▼
      0 => null
    ]
    "time" => 0.6
  ]
]
```

The problem is that the `bindings` value in second query is null. I want to get all `cars` and iterate into each of them and get as many users each car has.

How can I do that?

**Edit**
table schema:

car_user:
car_id user_id

cars:
car_id car_code price

users:
user_id user_type username password

Thanks

Comment: In simple, you want multiple users for the single car?

Comment: many-to-many => I want to have all cars and all users related to each. a car can have multiple users and a user can have multiple cars.

Comment: Yes Understand, with the above query you are trying to get all cars with its users  right  ?

Comment: Can you also show me the table schema?

Comment: yes that's right!

Comment: I edited the post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173065/discussion-between-dsraj-and-kodfire).

Comment: Did you set the `$primaryKey` in `Car` and `User`?

Comment: Bingo @JonasStaudenmeir That worked :) Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using custom primary keys, you have to specify them in your models:

```php
class Car extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'car_id';
}

class User extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
}
```